# What is פנאד"ש?

Tags: food, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk, shulchan-aruch

I know that it is a meat food, but what does it look like? ([שולחן ערוך יורה דעה צד, 8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.94.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))

I didn't find any explanations about it from Google.

Comment: Perhaps half-jokingly when we learned this we assumed it was [empanadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empanada). I don't have a source offhand but it seemed clear it was the same as פשטיד"א, which is described as dough stuffed with meat.

Comment: @robev In Belize, empanadas are known as panades.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found in the [article](https://www.ybz.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/Article_70.5(1).pdf) (p. 8 of the PDF) of [Eliezer Papo](https://in.bgu.ac.il/humsos/heblit/pages/staff/papo.aspx) that it is

> מאכל ספרדי דומה לבורקס שלנו היום – כיסנים ממולאים בבשר או בגבינה.‏
>
> a Sephardic food similar to our bourekas today – dumplings filled with meat or cheese.

It says that it is the same as the current [empanada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empanada), so [Robev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1739/robev)'s and [Joel K](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)'s guess was correct.